# How can I add a script to embedded Linux

Tags: shell-script, embedded, busybox, buildroot

I have a script (let's say Hello World), that I want to include to my embedded Linux. I'm using Buildroot and want to start the script in Busybox. But because I'm cross-compiling for the target I'm not sure where to put that script, that in the end it's gonna be compiled and can be executed in Busybox.

Answer (score 2):

a *shell-script* does not need to be compiled, in order to be run: the nature of *scripts* is to be run directly by an interpreter (your shell-implementation).

hence, you only need to put the script into a place where it will be found by your shell. for administrator-installed scripts, the preferred place is `/usr/local/bin` (or `/usr/local/sbin` if the script is to be run in "administrator mode").
make sure that the script has proper permissions.

```
# cp /path/to/script/hello_world.sh /usr/local/bin
# chown root.root /usr/local/bin/hello_world.sh
# chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/hello_world.sh
# hello_world.sh
Hi there!
#
```

Comment: yes i know. But where to put that script, that next time when i hit "make" I'm sure it's included in the generated image for the target?

Comment: this depends on your `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the script to run at start up and you are using the `busybox` init process in your system then place a script in the `/etc/init.d` directory.

You need to make sure that your script file name is of the form

```
SXFilename
```

where X is some integer that specifies the order that it is executed in - the lower the X value the earlier that the script will run. Depending on how you configured `buildroot` you should see some scripts similarly named already in your `/etc/init.d` directory. I am assuming above that you have not edited your `inittab` file to disable the running of these scripts of course.
Cross compiling is not an issue at all since the script is not compiled and is just executed using `ash` or `bash` if you have chosen to build `bash` package into your `buildroot` setup.

Comment: No I just wanted to have the script on my target, to make it run whenever I want, not only as init. And so I have to cross-compile the image (!) where I included my script as part of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I've found there are several ways to do so. I created an fs-overlay, hit make, and it was part of the Image.

Thanks for the advice.